# Create dictionary using max key values from another dictionary as keys, and lower values from original dictionary as list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Consider this dictionary:

```
webmap_items = {76453728: "Guatemala",
                12345678: "Guatemala",
                98765432: "Mexico",
                43285437: "Mexico",
                23265992: "Mexico"}
```

How can I turn it into a dictionary with the max value *for each country* as the key, and the remaining (lower) values as the values (in a list), like so:

```
output_dict = {76453728: [12345678], 98765432: [43285437, 23265992]}
```

Comment: Would be better to show what you tried and where you are facing problems. One area where I see the issue is that it has the value and key grouped in a weird way, so taht tells me it would need more that 1 iteration over the dict to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two steps by creating an intermediate and a final dictionary from the original one.  I have printed both so you can see how the answer evolves:

```
webmap_items = {76453728: "Guatemala",
                12345678: "Guatemala",
                98765432: "Mexico",
                43285437: "Mexico",
                23265992: "Mexico"}

intermediate = {}
countries = set(webmap_items.values())
for country in countries:
    intermediate[country] = []
    for key, value in webmap_items.items():
        if value == country:
            intermediate[country].append(key)
print(f'intermediate dictionary: {intermediate}')

final = {}
for key, value in intermediate.items():
    m = max(value)
    value.remove(m)
    final[m] = value

print(f'final dictionary: {final}')

#intermediate dictionary: {'Mexico': [98765432, 43285437, 23265992], 'Guatemala': [76453728, 12345678]}
#final dictionary: {98765432: [43285437, 23265992], 76453728: [12345678]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Comments inline to explain  -

```
from collections import defaultdict

output_dict = defaultdict(list)

#group keys by unique values in original dict
for i,j in ebmap_items.items():
    output_dict[j].append(i)
 
#Iterate and fetch max value as key, and remove max value from values   
output_dict = {max(v):list(set(v)-{max(v)}) for k,v in output_dict.items()}

### Alternatives ###
#output_dict = {max(v):[i for i in v if i!=max(v)] for k,v in output_dict.items()}
#output_dict = {max(v):list(filter(lambda x: x != max(v), v)) for k,v in output_dict.items()}

output_dict
```

```
{76453728: [12345678], 98765432: [43285437, 23265992]}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i guess i missed it. fixed :)